# K-fold cross validation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, k-fold

I want to do a k-fold cross validation on a dataset of 20 points and i was wondering, what would be a good value for k? I read a little bit about it and it seems like 5 could be a good value, but i was worried that 4 points for each fold would be too little data, and the error prediction could be wrong

Comment: Training a model with 20 points should be fast and a dataset with 20 points is usually considered small. Therefore, I would use leave-one-out i.e., you train with 19 points and test with only 1 in each fold.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!